# Rails: Root_path inside :default => declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently, I'm declaring the :default image_url as a hard-coded URL:

```
<%= image_url = GravatarImageTag::gravatar_url(current_user.email, :default => 'https://www.myapp.com/assets/unknown.png') %>
```

Which is throwing off my SSL certificate. So I'd like to do something like this:

```
<%= image_url = GravatarImageTag::gravatar_url(current_user.email, :default => root_path + '/assets/unknown.png') %>
```

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: whats the problem with that code?

Comment: The image_url is broken. It's only getting 'assets/unknown.png' — I need it to get the full URL

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to generate a fully-qualified URL for an image in your view.

You likely want something like `image_url('unknown.png')`

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
:default => root_path + '/assets/unknown.png'
```

with

```
:default => image_url("unknown.png")
```

(my answercorrected based on input from sevenseacat and izuriel)

Comment: There are rails helpers specifically designed for this purpose. Also, that is the file path, not the hostname.

Comment: @izuriel you're absolutely right, sorry.  Edited my answer.

Comment: I removed the downvote as it's now technically correct, but `image_url` is a view helper specifically designed to perform the operations you're doing to reference an image asset in the app. That should be used instead.

Comment: it's not technically correct - it won't work after asset compilation in production. You can't use non-digested pathnames like this.

Comment: @sevenseacat I didn't think about that, good catch. SteveTurczyn: Thanks for correcting the answer using standard view helpers!